# preg_replace only for non-english characters

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

I have a function that replace all hashtag with hrefs.

```
function hash_me($ret) {
     $ret = preg_replace('/(\#)([^\s]+)/', ' <a href="tag/$2">#$2</a> ', $ret);
}
```

It works well. It will return the string(and the rest non-hashtags words)with hashtags as links.

The thing is that i want to replace with hrefs **only** hashtags that contain english characters.Non-english hashtags should be ignored.

How can i merge/fit :

```
preg_match('/#[^a-z\d]/i',$da_string)
```

with the above function?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "non-english"? How do you differentiate between #centre (Canadian English) and #centre (French)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the unicode character class `Latin`:

```
function hash_me($ret) {
     $ret = preg_replace('/#([\p{Latin}0-9]+)/', ' <a href="tag/$1">$0</a> ', $ret);
}
```

But keep in mind that Latin and english are two things different.

For only english characters:

```
function hash_me($ret) {
     $ret = preg_replace('/#([a-z0-9]+)/i', ' <a href="tag/$1">$0</a> ', $ret);
}
```

or shorter:

```
function hash_me($ret) {
     $ret = preg_replace('/#([^\W_]+)/', ' <a href="tag/$1">$0</a> ', $ret);
}
```

Comment: !!! sorry, i had a mistake in my question. I meant non-english !!! I'll upvote anyway!Edit: accepted!

Comment: @Theodoros80: I have udapted my answer with this new requirement.